# Amazon S3 bucket access programmatically owned by third party

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to S3. One of our vendor is sharing a bucket and objects with us. We created an AWS account and added our team members as users. We can access data in the bucket via amazon aws cli. I am looking for java api to access data programatically.

I created a standalone code

```
    /*
     * Create your credentials file at ~/.aws/credentials (C:\Users\USER_NAME\.aws\credentials for Windows users) 
     * and save the following lines after replacing the underlined values with your own.
     *
     * [default]
     * aws_access_key_id = YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID
     * aws_secret_access_key = YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
     */

    AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client();
    Region usEast1 = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1);
    s3.setRegion(usEast1); 
    System.out.println("Listing objects");
        ObjectListing objectListing = s3.listObjects(new ListObjectsRequest()
                .withBucketName("exports.abx.t-z/xyz")
                );
        for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
            System.out.println(" - " + objectSummary.getKey() + "  " +
                    "(size = " + objectSummary.getSize() + ")");
        }
        System.out.println();
```

Now I am getting following exception

```
    Listing objects
Caught an AmazonServiceException, which means your request made it to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response for some reason.
Error Message:    The specified key does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey; Request ID: C80B0460828347D0)
HTTP Status Code: 404
AWS Error Code:   NoSuchKey
Error Type:       Client
Request ID:       C80B0460828347D0
```

I do not have the key to access. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 404 response indicates that your credentials are ok, but the thing you asked for does not exist.

This part of the code looks suspicious:

```
new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName("exports.abx.t-z/xyz")
```

The `withBucketName` method should be given the bucket name. I suspect that in your case, the bucket name should be simply "exports.abx.t-z". If you are looking to list all the objects in the "xyz" "folder" within that bucket, then you would want to do something like this:

```
new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName("exports.abx.t-z").withPrefix("xyz")
```

Comment: Hi Rob thanks for your your reply. That just worked :)