# Amazon S3 bucket data download programmatically owned by third party

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am new to S3. One of our vendor is sharing a bucket and objects with us. We created an AWS account and added our team members as users. We can access data in the bucket via amazon aws cli. I am looking for Java API to download data programmatically.

My code is :

```
/*
 * Create your credentials file at ~/.aws/credentials (C:\Users\USER_NAME\.aws\credentials for Windows users) 
 * and save the following lines after replacing the underlined values with your own.
 *
 * [default]
 * aws_access_key_id = YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID
 * aws_secret_access_key = YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
 */
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client();
Region usEast1 = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1);
s3.setRegion(usEast1);
System.out.println("Downloading an object");
S3Object object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("exports.xyz.t-z", "abc/2015/12/07/62542f4f0164689f5d18cf6-2c324750-6c47-11e5-0e29-00deb82fd81f"));
System.out.println("Content-Type: "  + object.getObjectMetadata().getContentType());
```

the error message is :

```
Downloading an object
Caught an AmazonServiceException, which means your request made it to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response for some reason.
Error Message:    The specified key does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey; Request ID: 3DD21D3934A4456D)
HTTP Status Code: 404
AWS Error Code:   NoSuchKey
Error Type:       Client
Request ID:       3DD21D3934A4456D
```

Now as the error message says : Keys does not exist I am not sure what the key is. The data is placed to the s3 by the vendor.

However I can access the data to see what is listed in the s3 directory, using following piece of code. (You also can refer to my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34358979/amazon-s3-bucket-access-programmatically-owned-by-third-party))

```
System.out.println("Listing objects");
ObjectListing objectListing = s3.listObjects(
    new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName("exports.xyz.t-z")
                            .withPrefix("abc/2015/12/07/62542f4f0164689f5d18cf6-2c324750-6c47-11e5-0e29-00deb82fd81f")
);
for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
    System.out.println(" - " + objectSummary.getKey() + "  " +
            "(size = " + objectSummary.getSize() + ")");
}
```

What would be the best recommended way to download the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to download the "directory" rather than a particular key in that directory.

You have code that lists the objects that have that prefix. When you try to download a file using `getObject(new GetObjectRequest())` the second parameter to the `GetObjectRequest` constructor must be one of the values that is returned when you call `objectSummary.getKey()`.

Comment: Thanks again Rob .. Actually I was about to post the answer.               Exactly, I have the code and same code to run the download, as you have mentioned ... I can create a stream of data... and process the stream. Is there a way we can just download the file directly to a local directory? or As you mentioned download the entire folder?

Comment: S3 is not a filesystem, so the concepts of folders do not apply.  See my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314051/how-to-download-files-from-amazon-s3/34314659#34314659) for more information on this.

Comment: I don't know of a way to "download the entire folder" as a single operation using the Java API - I think you have to list the objects and download each object explicitly. If you can use the CLI interface, there is a single command that does this. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html